# Django whitenoise is fine for production but gives 404 for debug mode

Tags: python, django, whitenoise

I use django `white noise` and it works when `DEBUG = False`; however when setting `DEBUG = True`, I cannot load the image anymore and get 404 response.

Note: I am aware of hard-refresh. I already used static collection and django migrations.

Here is my code:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
cd mysite/
python3 manage.py migrate
(after setup settings.py):
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

```
pip show whitenoise|grep Version
Version: 6.2.0
```

mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

```
import os
from whitenoise import WhiteNoise
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from mysite.settings import BASE_DIR

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = WhiteNoise(application, root=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")  )
```

mysite/mysite/asgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
```

mysite/mysite/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

mysite/mysite/settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-u5pg-ef=-o0zzi16fk)xf1p8dsz7t$$vayc$3x1y(r01kb0rkg'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
WHITENOISE_MANIFEST_STRICT = False
```

Copy the image and make sure the image does exist:

```
ls staticfiles/images/hi.jpg 
staticfiles/images/hi.jpg
```

The url to load:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/hi.jpg

When `DEBUG=True` in the settings:
[image: error 404]

But when `DEBUG=False`,

[image: Hi image]

---

Last failed try:

```
DEBUG = True
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = None if DEBUG else os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
WHITENOISE_MANIFEST_STRICT = False
```

.

Comment: I can provide any further information if needed.

Comment: Try disabling compression when debug is true.

Comment: @pygeek, if you mean commenting out STATICFILES_STORAGE, it will not impact neither the debug nor the release mode. Using `STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"` will not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me is as follows:

settings.py

```
if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS=['staticfiles']
    STATIC_ROOT = None
else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS=[]
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Answer (score 2):

In debug mode, Django takes over the handling of the static files, which means that by default django looks for static files in this folder `my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg`, if you had placed static files somewhere else you probably need to add it to `STATICFILES_DIRS=[]`.

If you don't have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your installed apps, you may also want to try adding the below in your urls.py

```py
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

If you want whitenoise in development, you will need to runsever with `-nostatic` option turned on. If you don't want to write `-nostatic` command everytime then just add `whitenoise.runserver_nostatic` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

refer the documentation for more information: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#using-whitenoise-in-development

Comment: In release mode, I get `?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.`
I think it should be like this `if DEBUG: STATICFILES_DIRS = ...  else STATIC_ROOT = ....` and also no `urlpatterns` involved.

Comment: @ar2015 The urlpattern is required if you don't have `django.contrib.staticfiles ` in your installed apps, its just another way to serve without `django.contrib.staticfiles`. I'll clear it up in the edit

Comment: @ar2015 besides `STATICFILES_DIRS` is also necessary when using collectstatic command.

Answer (score 0):

I always configure the `STATIC_ROOT` like this:

```py
STATIC_ROOT = None if DEBUG else BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
```

for more info on why and how does this work you could read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Comment: Thanks Mahdi. I tried this and last try failed too. I updated the question. Even `STATIC_ROOT = None` does not help in debug mode.